# JQuery .each Against a Variable

Tags: jquery

How does one specify a target variable with the jquery each function? I am performing a get request and placing the results in a variable. I want to run the each function on that variable to pull out all the id tags. Many thanks.

```
$.get("somepage.php?id=45 #my_target_div", function(data) {
   $.each(function(data, "#id") {
   });
});
```

Comment: Q. How do I find out how jquery function `x()` works? A. Read [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) for [that function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$.get()` method doesn't allow you to filter down the results with a selector like `.load()` does, and your use of `.each()` is wrong.

This would allow you to loop through all elements that have an id attribute inside the `my_target_div`.

```
$.get("somepage.php?id=45", function(data) {    
   $("<div />").html(data).find("#my_target_div [id]").each(function(){
       // annoying alert
       alert(this.id);
       // or the more appealing console log
       // console.log(this.id);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`$.each` takes 2 parameters.  The object you want to loop over, and a callback to call on each element.

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
});
```

P.S. The syntax you are using for the URL doesn't work with `$.get`.  It only works with `$().load`.

Comment: Cool, I changed to load thank you. I still don't understand how to pick out all the IDs from that.